# Cognito forms Question - can you view the page url the form entry was submitted from

Tags: cognito-forms

Im not sure if this is possible but here goes.I want to add a ask a question form to a courses section of my website.I can add the javascript embed to courses template and the form will appear on all my course webpages( there is around a 100 pages).

I need to know what url the question comes from as sometimes the questions are vague and the admin needs to know the exact course the question is referring too.

Also I want to do a report to see which courses generate the most questions.So is there anyway in Cognitoforms to record what url the form entry comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is nothing built-in to support this. However, if you are embedding your form in your website, you can have you website pre fill information into the form into invisible fields.

Check this support page out.
https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/data-integration/prefilling-a-form